# When to use pivot wider/longer?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

```
ID    Variables     Value 
Zero  Pregnancies    2 
Zero  Glucose        3
One   Pregnancies    8
One   Glucose        9
```

Anyone know how I can get a table that looks like the one above into something that looks like this?

```
Variables    Zero     One
Pregnancies   2        8
Glucose       3        9
```

Using exclusively `dplyr` or `tidyr`?

***If a better title would fit this question, please let me know***

Answer (score 1):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Value ~ Variables + ID, df1)
```

---

Or with `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df1, names_from = ID, values_from = Value)
```

Comment: The xtabs method didn't work but the second one did! Thank You. I had tried pivot_wider but kept using 'cols' instead of 'names_from'. Do you happen to know the 'cols' argument does?